# Как использовать переменную из функции вне функции?

Tags: javascript, функции

Имеется такой код:

```
    var RawRandom = Math.random();

function GetRoundRandom() {
    var MaxValue = document.getElementById('max').value;
    var MaxValueLength = MaxValue.length;
    console.log("MaxValueLength: ", MaxValueLength)
    var MaxValueLengthPow = Math.pow(10, MaxValueLength);
    console.log("MaxValueLengthPow: ", MaxValueLengthPow);
    var HalfRound = RawRandom * MaxValueLengthPow;
    console.log("HalfRound: ", HalfRound);
    var StringHalfRound = String(HalfRound);
    console.log("StringHalfRound: ", StringHalfRound);
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < StringHalfRound.length; i++) {
        if (StringHalfRound[i] == '.') {
            var StringRound = StringHalfRound.substring(0, i);
            console.log("StringRound: ", StringRound);
        }
    }
    var RoundRandom = Number(StringRound);
    console.log("RoundRandom: ", RoundRandom);
    return (RoundRandom);
}
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы RoundRandom можно было использовать вне функции.

Думал что для этого нужен return, но он не работает (как со скобками так и без них).

Comment: ну так убери `var` в строке `var RoundRandom = Number(StringRound);`  ..... или пиши `var test = GetRoundRandom()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, и чем это должно помочь?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin что именно? а почему тогда кое-кто этот вариант описал в ответе?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, речь шла о `var RoundRandom = Number(StringRound);`, до правки. Смысла данное изменение не имеет.

Comment: Товарищ, топикстартер, Вы бы уже попробовали внести изменения - да посмотрели результат

Comment: @VasiliyRusin `Смысла данное изменение не имеет.` - вполне себе, если знаете js

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, убрав var вы лишь добьетесь `Uncaught ReferenceError: RoundRandom is not defined`. Вы и сами это понимаете, если знаете JS.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin ну значит вы не умеете пользоваться JS еще, что у вас он `is not defined`. Ибо надо правильно юзать)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я Вас не понимаю, если переменная не объявлена, в строгом режиме интерпретатор выбросит ошибку. Что значит "не умеете пользоваться"? Или вы предлагаете надеятся на то что в 2017 какой то браузер не будет использовать строгий режим по умолчанию?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin не просто так существует `use strict` который ввели для того, чтобы не сломать к чертям весь старый код. Или вы думаете что, разработчики браузеров совсем на голову больные по умолчанию включить его, чтоб все сайты с кодом на ES5 померли? серьезно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Вы видимо совершенно не понимаете о чем говорите. ` "use strict" ` введен в спецификацию с EcmaScript 5.1 И он исправляет проблемы ES3 и ниже, а не наоборот. [Почитайте](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) о строгом режиме. И да, Chromium с 50 (если ничего не путаю) версии использует ` "use strict" ` по умолчанию.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin `исправляет проблемы ES3 и ниже, а не наоборот.` -
 про ES3 я ничего не писал, так к слову.......`если ничего не путаю` - да, 100% вы путаете......мне не надо тыкать доками, я знаю как работает. Вы, если не способны применить особенности js так, чтобы всё работало то, пожалуй, это вам надо подучить что-то ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Не передергивайте. Вы утверждали, что в ES5 работать не будет (`чтоб все сайты с кодом на ES5 померли?`), я лишь объясняю что для ES5 этот режим и был введен. Если бы Вы знали как работает - спора бы не было. А использование `особенности js` это худшее что Вы можете предложить новичку, ведь смысл строгого режима как раз в том что бы плавно уйти от этих **проблем** языка, а не особенностей.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin если для вас особенности == проблемы (а особенностей ооооочень много), то, может не стоит насиловать себя и как мышка колоться плакать но продолжать кушать кактус?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если для вас то от чего разработчики пытаются избавится при развитии языка !== проблемы, то может и `with` в продакшене будете использовать? В любом случае, мы так перейдем на личности. Спор того не стоит. Использование того что разработчики собираются убрать в будущих версиях - **плохо**. Я надеюсь вы с этим согласны. Не сим предлагаю мир.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin я приведу некоторые особенности. Смотрите: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DM1czpAXkAAH8qF.jpg ну и известный wat с конференции https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat (про js начиная с 01:20). Разработчики не будут это убирать, но это и не проблема, это особенность (всё написано в спеке, кстати)...Это просто надо использовать)) так да - мир

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция возвращает RoundRandom
cоответственно что бы использовать значение RoundRandom вне функции достаточно задать ее глобально.

```
var RoundRandom = GetRoundRandom();
```

**UPD.** Я бы не рекомендовал использование `String()` и `Number()` по идеологическим причинам. Гораздо чаще используются метод `.toString()` и функции `parseInt()` для целых, и `parseFloat()` для вещественных

---

Весь код

```
function GetRoundRandom() {
    var MaxValue = document.getElementById('max').value;
    var MaxValueLength = MaxValue.length;
    console.log("MaxValueLength: ", MaxValueLength)
    var MaxValueLengthPow = Math.pow(10, MaxValueLength);
    console.log("MaxValueLengthPow: ", MaxValueLengthPow);
    var HalfRound = RawRandom * MaxValueLengthPow;
    console.log("HalfRound: ", HalfRound);
    var StringHalfRound = String(HalfRound);
    console.log("StringHalfRound: ", StringHalfRound);
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < StringHalfRound.length; i++) {
        if (StringHalfRound[i] == '.') {
            var StringRound = StringHalfRound.substring(0, i);
            console.log("StringRound: ", StringRound);
        }
    }
    var RoundRandom = Number(StringRound);
    console.log("RoundRandom: ", RoundRandom);
    return RoundRandom;
}

var RoundRandom = GetRoundRandom();
```

Comment: А вернуть именно через return можно?

Comment: Мне кажется, такой ответ запутывает. Особенно, если человек не знает про области видимости переменных. Для ответа лучше использовать промежуточную переменную

Comment: Ну так в коде вы и возвращаете `return RoundRandom;`

Comment: Консоль выдает ошибку: RoundRandom is not defined

Comment: @brachkoff, сверьте ваш код с тем что привел я.

Comment: @Дмытрык, вероятнее всего вы правы, однако отвечаю исходя из постановки задачи.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin в вашем случае получается null

Comment: @brachkoff, значит результатом работы функции является null.  Ошибка не в том как задается `RoundRandom`. А в том как выполняется функция.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin внутри функции она равна числу

Comment: @brachkoff вы можете привести код, как именно вы проверяете что получается `null`

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема - скрипт ссылался на значение функции, а функция загружвлвсь по клику (те на момент загрузки скрипта значение функции было null). Для того чтобы все заработало нужно было завернуть весь код в функцию, внутри которой функция  GetRoundRandom вызывалась автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

Код получился такой:

```
function GetRandom() {
    var RawRandom = Math.random();

    function GetRoundRandom() {
        var MaxValue = document.getElementById('max').value;
        var MaxValueLength = MaxValue.length;
        console.log("MaxValueLength: ", MaxValueLength)
        var MaxValueLengthPow = Math.pow(10, MaxValueLength);
        console.log("MaxValueLengthPow: ", MaxValueLengthPow);
        var HalfRound = RawRandom * MaxValueLengthPow;
        console.log("HalfRound: ", HalfRound);
        var StringHalfRound = String(HalfRound);
        console.log("StringHalfRound: ", StringHalfRound);
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < StringHalfRound.length; i++) {
            if (StringHalfRound[i] == '.') {
                var StringRound = StringHalfRound.substring(0, i);
                console.log("StringRound: ", StringRound);
            }
        }
        var RoundRandom = Number(StringRound);
        console.log("RoundRandom: ", RoundRandom);
        return RoundRandom;
    }
    GetRoundRandom();
    var RoundRandom = GetRoundRandom();
    alert(RoundRandom);
}
```

Comment: Вам не нужно дважды вызвать `GetRoundRandom();`